# Adding php code to dynamic homepage template in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    if (is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_type= $current_user->data->user_type;
        if($user_type=='client')
        {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink(get_page_by_path( 'client-dashboard' )));
            exit;
        }
        if($user_type=='writer')
        {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink(get_page_by_path( 'writer-dashboard' ))); 
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I want to insert this in my homepage template. However the problem is that I use a theme named Layers that dynamically creates pages and stores it in the database so there is no home.php / index.php or anything like that to edit.

Instead it's stored as a post in the database, but there are 30+ revision posts in the database as well.

So I added this code to both the original Post, ID918, as well as the last revision post. However it doesn't work.

I also tried to add this code to the header.php, adding the condition is_home() but that didn't work either. On my previous site I simply had a home.php that contained all of the code so it was very easy to add this code to the opening section but now with these dynamically created posts I somehow can't get it done.

Do I need to add this code to every single revision post of the homepage? Or shouldn't I put it in the post_content row but in another row instead? Kind of clueless that I can't get such simple thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

I had to add the code to the header.php of my child theme instead of parent theme in front of `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and add `if (is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() )` and it all of a sudden worked, after trying many ways for over an hour.